# How to check if a function-like macro is defined?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a line in my code that looks like this:

```
#ifndef MACRO(n)
```

This actually works fine on most compilers. However, this fails on Solaris, because the official syntax is `# ifndef identifier new-line groupopt` and parentheses are not allowed in identifiers.

What is the proper way to check whether this macro is defined?

Comment: To clarify. You already know how to check if it is defined, via `ifdef MACRO`. You want to know specifically if it is a *function* macro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont need `(n)`, actually gcc will complain if you use it:

```
warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive
```

this is because `#ifndef` expects an identifier not expression, `(n)` is probably ignored by preprocessor

It should suffice to simply check with macro definition name:

```
#ifndef MACRO
```